# NoSuchMethod error for json.put in runtime for junit test case

Tags: json, junit, mockito

Written my Junit test case as below. Getting some no such method error when i run my testcases.

```
ResponseObject res = initialized with some data;
ServiceImpl servie;
@Test
public void methidName(){

  ResponseObject mockObject= Mockito.spy(new ResponseObject(data));
  mockObject.setters() // more setters follows
  doReturn(someretunObject).when(mockObject).somethod();
  // calling actual method here now
   service.transfor();

}
```

Actual Classes

```
ResponseOject {
 List<JSONObject> jsonList;
  ......
 }

ServiceImpl{
  public SearchResponse transfor(SearchResponse response) {
    JSONObject obj= new JSONObject(response.getConent());
    JSONArray arr= (JSONArray) obj.get("RootNode");
    ArrayList<JSONObject> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0i<arr.size();i++){
    list.add(arr.get(i));
       }
 // doing some sorting here with the list
  Collections.sort(list, comparator);
/**/ setting the sorted collection to response object as below**
    response.setJsonList(list);
  JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
  obj.put("rootNode", response.getJsonList);
 // getting error in above line during Junit testcase run
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement**

```
  Getting error at this point in actual method
  obj.put("rootNode", response.getJsonList);

 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.put(Llava/lang/String;Ljava/lanf/
    Collection;)Lorg/json/JSONObject
```

Any reason why it so. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the method you think you are?  Your test is invoking this method:

```
service.transfor()
```

but your code example shows this method:

```
public SearchResponse transfor(SearchResponse response)
```

The one you showed takes an input parameter, but you aren't passing one, so it appears you are not invoking the method you intend to be testing.  If this is just a mistake in what you posted, then you should look at what object you have mocked to be returned by the `response.getJsonList` call.  If it is returning an object that is of a type that is different from the type required by the `obj.put` method then you could get this error.